# How do I calculate with Tax Deductible Voluntary Contributions?

Tags: hong-kong

I followed the steps on [Activ Payroll](https://www.activpayroll.com/news-articles/hong-kong-introduces-pension-contribution-tax-incentive)

> [image]

, but I can't calculate these integers in [SCMP](https://www.scmp.com/business/companies/article/2176727/hong-kong-moves-increase-tax-exemption-boost-uptake-annuity-plans).

> [image]

6. Here's my work for 2. $60K/month = $720K/year. But this is just case 1 overhead in Activ Payroll! Why do the exemption amounts differ?
7. How do cases 2 and 3 differ? What caused these different integers?
8. Here's my work for 4. 15K HKD/month = 180K/year. Total taxable income = 180K/year – 18K (Mandatory MPF contribution) = 162K.

   Taxable income after TVC of $60K/year = 162 –  60 = 102K.

   Thus tax savings = 0.15 × (162 - 102)K = 9K. But SCMP calculated "HK$180 tax payments in a year".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Employee Mandatory Contribution is not always $18,000 per year. It is 5% x Gross Income capped at $18,000, i.e. if Income is $180,000, Employee Mandatory Contributon is $9,000.

As per 2019-20 Budget Proposal, the first $132,000 Income is tax free.

The tax rate of 15% is only applicable if it is beneficial to you. 
In other cases, it is 2% for first $50,000 after $132,000, 6% for next $50,000, 10% for the next $50,000, 14% for the next $50,000, and 17% for the remainer.

In general, I would just ignore what the newspaper says as they intend to simplify the idea for less informed readers.

Please just use the official calculator to experiment with different income:
https://www.ird.gov.hk/eng/ese/st_comp_2019_20_budget/stcfrm.htm

[image: Sample Calculation]

Furthermore, the SCMP article that you cited was about increasing the (Proposed) Tax Deductible MPF Voluntary Contributions from $36,000 to $60,000, not about from $0 to $60,000. Therefore, the "benefit" cited by the article are incremental benefits.